# How to access the public boolean variable in run() method in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How to access the variable `boolean` `check_point` value in `run()` method ?

```
public class Transciever {

public boolean check_point = true;

  public void run() {

                while (true) {

                         System.out.println("before client listening...");
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        System.out.println("after socket accept");
                        check_point = false; 
   }
  }
}
```

I'm not able to change the value of variable `boolean` `check_point` from `run()` method, but I'm able to access other normal methods.

Comment: What ever you are doing is the correct way .And your code works fine

Comment: What made you think that you can't access the variable?

Comment: If you are trying to run the `run()` method in its own thread, you need to implement `Thread` (or at least `Runnable`) in your class.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to access the `check_point` method outside the thread.
first the `Transciever` is not thread because you havn't implement the runnable method.
you need a getter method in order to other classes able to get the flag, and for getting the value thread instance is not required, you need to keep `Transciever` class instance 
so this should be like this.

```
class Main{
 public static void main(String...arg){
  Transciever t=new Transciever();
  new Thread(t).start();
  //......
  //......
  boolean flag=t.getFlag();
 }
}

public class Transciever implements Runnable{
private volatile boolean check_point = true;
public boolean getFlag(){ return this.check_point;}
  @Override
  public void run() {
                while (true) {

                         System.out.println("before client listening...");
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        System.out.println("after socket accept");
                        check_point = false; 
   }
  }
}
```

another example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616115/Java-Thread-Example#ai)

Comment: +1 for making `check_point` __volatile__.  I'm not sure I understand the question or the answers, but `check_point` is going to be useless unless it's declared __volatile__.  At this time, this the only answer that does that.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing changing the value of check_point is what you want to do as a break condition for your while loop, however you never quit the while loop (`while(true)` is an infinite loop). Put `while (check_point)` to get out of the loop!

Comment: donot consider while loop .... Pl tell me about check_point variable .... I can access the check_point variable from run() method

Comment: You can access it! You are doing everything right, except for the infinite loop you are creating!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it ***appears*** to you that you are not able to access the `check_point` public field in your code, is because *you never reference it in your while loop condition*.  I assume that you are expecting the loop to end once you set `check_point` to `false`.  However, *you never reference `check_point` in the loop condition!* So, even though `check_point` ends up being perfectly well false after the statement, the loop still continues forever.

Also, you misspelled "Transceiver" in your code.

What you probably intended was:

```
public class Transceiver implements Thread {

    public boolean check_point = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (check_point) { //loop condition changed
            ServerSocket serverSocket = // [...]
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            check_point = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if this is your actual final code, I would recommend you instead just do it like this, without the loop at all (you can still keep the `check_point` field, which I assume is used by other classes to check if the communication is done?:

```
public class Transceiver implements Thread {
    public boolean check_point = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = // [...]
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        check_point = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am making a lot of assumptions about what you intended here, though, so please correct me if I am wrong.